# How can I make my isSorted function faster?

Tags: java, performance, scala, sorting

I made an `isSorted` function in Scala and Java as well and when I measured the time of functions' run I saw that the Scala version was very slow. It ran about 3.2 sec for 10000 Int but java version just ran about 10 ms!

How can I make faster my Scala version?

**Scala:**

```
def main(args: Array[String]) ={
    println(isSorted(getArray, (x:Int,y:Int) => x<y ))
}
def isSorted[A](items : Array[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean) : Boolean = items match{
  case Array(_) => true 
  case Array(x,y) =>cond(x,y)
  case Array(_*) => cond(items(0),items(1)) && isSorted(items tail,cond)
}
```

**Java:**

```
public static void main(String... args){
    Sorter sorter=new Sorter();
    System.out.println(sorter.isSorted(sorter.getList(),new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    }));
}
public <A> boolean isSorted(List<A> items, Comparator<A> cond){
    for(int i=1;i<items.size();i++){
            if(cond.compare(items.get(i-1), items.get(i)) < 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestions?

I would like to use Scala, but this bad performance scared me!
Can I keep Scala's syntactic sugar?

Comment: Java 8, which will release in a week, will support Lambdas, so you can use some of the syntaxic sugar. Keep in mind though that Scala is much less verbose than Java is.

Comment: I think the Java version can be faster.... would that review be interesting to you?

Comment: Yes I know I wrote it down. I am interested in making faster the Scala version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is simply that your two solutions are not equivalent. For example, you would probably not use `Array`, but barring that, a direct translation of the Java code to Scala would be:

```
def isSorted[A](items: Array[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
    for (i <- 1 until items.length if !cond(items(i - 1), items(i))) {
      return false
    }
    return true
}
```

However, using an `Array` in Scala is a bit uncommon, and one would rather use `Seq` instead. Especially, a `LinearSeq` promises an efficient `tail` operation but slow indexing, this is reversed for an `IndexedSeq`.

```
@tailrec // remind the compiler that the recursion can be eliminated
def isSorted[A](items: LinearSeq[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = items match {
  case Seq()     => true  // you forgot to handle empty input!
  case Seq(_)    => true 
  case x :: tail => cond(x, tail.head) && isSorted(tail, cond)
}
```

But in this specific case, destructuring is actually silly: The `isSorted` test should male sense for *any* iterable (let's hope that it terminates, but that isn't our problem). It doesn't actually matter that much here that we can't do much destructuring for a general trait like `Iterable`. This here is a fairly elegant solution, but I wouldn't make any bets about performance.

```
def isSorted[A](items: Iterable[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean =
  items.isEmpty || (items zip items.tail forall (pair => cond(pair._1, pair._2)))
```

The `zip` method joins two lists pairwise: `items = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)` would then produce `((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))`.

I am not sure whether any of these solutions would actually be faster – it's to be expected that Scala is a bit slower than Java, but the difference for a careful implementation should not be as large as in your question.

---

Style notes:

- Always annotate tail recursive functions with `@tailrec` (from the `scala.annotation` package). This will either perform a tail call optimization or produce an error if the compiler is unable to do so.
- When specifying the type of a variable, put a space after the `:`, but not before: `name: Type`. ([source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#annotations))
- Invoke methods by using `.`, except when the method is an operator or takes a function as parameter – `items.tail` instead of `items tail` ([source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html))
- In general, the spacing around your operators is inconsistent. A comma should always be followed by a space, and binary operators like `=` or `<` should have a space on either side. ([source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#symbolic_methodsoperators))

Comment: I just compared your last method to his Scala method and your's MUCH faster. The test was an array with 20000 numbered from 0 to 20000. His method took around 5.7 seconds on my machine. Your method took less than 50ms. I couldn't get your @tailrec method to run (I got a MatchError with both mutable and immutable collections). My code: https://gist.github.com/luiscubal/9476082 (sorry if this is not idiomatic, I'm new to Scala)

Answer (score 1):

Amon's solution is simple and functional but it doesn't work on arrays and other IndexedSeqs.
If you want a general isSorted method that works on any sequential datastructure and is very fast you need to use an iterator.

```
def isSorted[T](list: Iterable[T])(lt: (T, T) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(last: T, iter: Iterator[T]): Boolean = {
    if(!iter.hasNext) true
    else {
      val elem = iter.next
      if(lt(elem, last)) false
      else loop(elem, iter)
    }
  }

  val iter = list.iterator
  !iter.hasNext || loop(iter.next, iter)
}
```

As far as I know the only way to make this even faster is by specialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I love languages for their quirks. I would use `list` and:

```
def IsSorted(l:List[Int]) = (l, l.tail).zipped.forall(_ <= _)
```

**source**: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852471/idiomatic-construction-to-check-whether-a-collection-is-ordered)

Comment: If you did not get my hint - "If you plan on using something like ´.elements.toList´ then you are better of using list in the first place".